# Cross Device Rich Text Formatting

Tags: android, ios, web

We're trying to work on a feature where users can enter rich text (Bold, numbered/bulleted lists, underlines, links) for content, but this content needs to be displayed in multiple places:

- On browser based websites/apps.
- In native iOS/Android apps.

What's the best format to use for storing this data? We are considering storing the text as html, but is this adequate, or is there a better solution/option to storing this data and rendering it?

Can native iOS/Android apps display html content well in native apps amidst other native controls, or will this text have to be converted to a different format to render well?

Thanks!

Comment: I find that HTML is not really well suited for Android. Displaying it in an `WebView` is quiet expensive and can't be placed inside any other scrolling `View`. `Html.fromHtml(...)` has a very reduced functionality (no bullet lists). Creating an [SpannedString](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannedString.html) from HTML with [HtmlSpanner](https://github.com/NightWhistler/HtmlSpanner) works okay. So does [Bypass](http://uncodin.github.io/bypass/) for Markdown, which is also available for iOS (but I've only tested the Android version).